# Emit D-Bus signal using GDBus without owning a well-known name

Tags: glib, dbus, gdbus

I would like to use dbus to signal other instances of the same family of applications.
It seems that to issue a signal I must execute a `g_bus_own_name`, emit the signal when the name is acquired, then `g_bus_unown_name`.
This seems like a bit of palava just to send a signal.
When the name is acquired, another instance of the application will hang waiting for this instance to 'unown' the name.

The deprecated way of `dbus_message_new_signal`/`dbus_connection_send` was much more straight forward.

Is there a simpler way to send the signal (without **owning** the name).

Comment: I think the answer to to abandon the high level gdbus stuff and use the low-level routine .. `g_dbus_connection_emit_signal`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Michael K says, use [`g_dbus_connection_emit_signal()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusConnection.html#g-dbus-connection-emit-signal). You only have to own a [well-known name](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-protocol-names-bus) if you want other users of the bus to be able to address your application by that well-known name, rather than a unique name which changes every time you connect to the bus.